# I can't spawn in other types of mobspawners

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit

I very well know how to do `/spawner cow` and such, but when I try to do `/give <User> 52:4` (zombie spawner) it doesn't work; it gives me only a pig spawner. I am very annoyed, and my player wants a spawner shop. What do I do?

In case you want to know, here are my plugins: Essentials, WorldBoarder, Factions, Multicore, vaults, Playervaults

Comment: If your talking about mods... The community can't help you. If your not try getting a spawn EGG and right click the spawner with it. This should place the mob inside the spawner.

Comment: Im talking about a 1.9 minecraft server spigot

Comment: Try using the TooManyItems mod as it can get spawners

Comment: also Item Id Like the item id dont work

Comment: I have a server

Comment: I just want the ids

Comment: Currently it doesn't work with Mojang commands. Try getting a plugin for it

Comment: I would suggest using MCedit to create your own spawners from the type of mob you wish to spawn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Use /Summon Command](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/285722/cant-use-summon-command)

Comment: I disagree with the dupe flag, OP is asking for help with the give command which should give a specific spawner in his inventory.

Answer (score 1):

While the essentials /give command doesn't work; their is a work around this; from vanilla.

```
/give @p mob_spawner 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{EntityId:Skeleton}, display:{Name:Skeleton Spawner}}
```

(or in bukkit:)

```
/minecraft:give @p mob_spawner 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{EntityId:Skeleton}, display:{Name:Skeleton Spawner}}
```

I suggest getting a rename plugin like SimpleRename and use it to rename them with different colors (just to make them easier to visualize).

More on it:

https://www.kirsle.net/blog/entry/minecraft-monster-spawners

If that doesn't work, do:

```
/give @p mob_spawner 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{SpawnData:{id:Skeleton},SpawnPotentials:[]}}
```

or in bukkit:

```
/minecraft:give @p mob_spawner 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{SpawnData:{id:Skeleton},SpawnPotentials:[]}}
```

After you rename them; do /iteminfo to get the id.

Comment: Perfect, I'm not the OP but this works for me and i will be using it in future instead of MCedit, (which can be a right pain)