# Can't Use /Summon Command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit

Recently I've been messing around with making a few minigames, and have used a few plugins to help make it easier to create and run them. However, a newer one I'm making requires me to use the /summon command in order to spawn zombies. However, no matter what I put in, I can't spawn hostile mobs. All other entities still spawn perfectly fine. Strangely, the /spawnmob command which comes with Essentials can summon hostile mobs fine. I would rather use /summon since it's more customizable though.
Here's a list of plugins I have installed.

- Essentials
- EssentialsChat
- HolographicDisplays
- PermissionsEx
- setspawn
- [A plugin I have made, just a simple timer]
- Vault
- VoxelSniper
- WorldEdit
- WorldGuard

Please let me know if you have any ideas on what I'm doing incorrectly or isn't functioning the way it should.

Comment: Does WorldGuard prevent mobs from spawning? /summon won't work in regions with mob spawn denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Essentials overrides the `/summon` command.

To circumvent this, you can either do this in the bukkit.yml, or use a different command.

The command to override it is `/minecraft:summon` then the arguments as per normal. This works for other overridden commands, like `/minecraft:give`, if you prefer the default syntax/arguments.

Comment: I have just attempted this,  bukkit:minecraft just says "unknown command" while minecraft:summon results in the same error (Username: Unable to summon object)
Note: I've made sure to use the correct formatting at casing for the command, which seems to be the issue for most other players.

Comment: @Thane Could you give an example of a command you've tried using, and I can see if I can fix it.

Comment: `/summon Zombie; /minecraft:summon Zombie; /bukkit:summon Zombie`   EDIT: I've gone into the server.properties and commented out the _spawn-monsters=true_ option. After rebooting the server the properties uncommented it, but somehow the issue is fixed. No idea why this fixed it, but it did.

Comment: Essentials should support /summon just fine, since it's using /s for summoning players to you (alias /tphere).

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the coordinates!

Since you are using Essentials, I believe you have to do:
`/minecraft:summon (mob) ~ ~ ~`

You can replace the ~s with coordinates or leave it as it is to summon a mob right at the location where it's being summoned.

Comment: /summon works with Essentials.