# Did using the /give command to get items with attributes change in 1.17.1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, version-differences

I've already stumbled upon some similar threads, but none on version 1.17. So my issue is, I want to make custom items (sword, armors…) with custom attributes. I tried copy/pasting some commands, but none worked. It keeps telling me that the item name is unknown, here's an example of command :

```
/give @p diamond_sword{Unbreakable:1,AttributeModifiers:[{Slot:"mainhand", AttributeName:"generic.attack_damage", Amount:100000.0, UUID:[I; -1, -1, -1, -1]},{Slot:"mainhand", AttributeName:"generic.movement_speed", Amount:1, UUID:[I; -1, -1, -1, -1]}]} 1
```

It's from a tutorial for Minecraft 1.16.5, so I suppose that it does not work the same in 1.17.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Use /Summon Command](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/285722/cant-use-summon-command)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that's not `/attribute`, that's `/give`, you're using attribute modifiers. The command should work, or at the very least not say the item name is unknown - it sounds like you've got a plugin here that's using the old `/give` syntax. What happens if you use `/minecraft:give @p ...` instead?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes it was because of a plugin using it's own /give, so the /minecraft:give work fine. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Althoris Please mark this as the answer using the check mark